# Calling a query error

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I have get this problem when I try to call a query on a graph,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hostname' of undefined
    at Request.send (./node_modules/neo4j-js/lib/Neo4jApi.js:195:27)
    at new Request (./node_modules/neo4j-js/lib/Neo4jApi.js:188:9)
    at Graph.query (./node_modules/neo4j-js/lib/Graph.js:84:55)
    at ./server.js:12:11
    at ./node_modules/neo4j-js/lib/Neo4jApi.js:143:4
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (./node_modules/neo4j-js/lib/Neo4jApi.js:262:6)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:938:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Here is my following code. I know the graph exists and have run this query in the browser and via Python so I know I should be able to.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var neo4j = require('neo4j-js');
neo4j.connect('**********', function (error, graph) {
    // do something with graph object
    console.log(graph)
    var query = [
        "MATCH (n { id: 2 })-[r]->nbr", 
        'RETURN n,r,nbr'
    ];
    graph.query(query.join('\n'), function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(err.stack);
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var relationship = results[i].r;
                var node = results[i].m;
                console.log(node);
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You're connecting to ******** -- that seems like a problem.  Also, you're referring to results[i].m in the else clause; the variable m shouldn't be defined, so if you get that far, that should also be a problem.

Comment: There's a valid address. I just took it out for privacy reasons. It's the graph.query line that's throwing the error.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Ya, I was reassigning one of the variables later on. Dynamic programming languages let you do that by accident.